# Bootstrap 4: make images larger than the container

Tags: css, bootstrap-4, width, padding

I have a website with articles included in a Bootstrap 4 grid:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-10">
            // content
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

(Please note that I intentionally use `container` and not `container-fluid`.)

The content contains images:

```
<figure>
    <img src="x.jpg" class="img-fluid myimage">
</figure>
```

I would like to ensure that these images, on medium or bigger devices, are a little wider than the grid (e.g. 110%, without being full-width):

[image]

How could I solve this problem?

Comment: did you try negative margin?

Comment: use 3 divs, inside the container, col-md-10, col-md-11 and col-md-10, hope it will solve your issue. here the col-md-11 will be the middle div, which will contain the image.

Comment: @TemaniAfif Ok for the negative margins. But: how can i center the images as in the mockup above?

Comment: Why don't you do the other way? Make image width 100% and add padding so the text occupies for example 80% of the space? Maybe it would be easier.